# How to add a header for a pact provider test using PactVerificationSpringProvider and Junit5?

Tags: spring, testing, junit5, provider, pact

I am trying to write a pact provider test using [junit5spring](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/junit5spring/) .

Currently I get the exception:

```
1) Verifying a pact between external-service and my-app - includes headers "Content-Type" with value "[application/json]"

    1.1) header: Expected a header 'Content-Type' but was missing
```

How should I add the header?
I already tried like this:

```
@TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationSpringProvider.class)
    public void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context, HttpRequest request) {
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        if (context != null) {
            context.verifyInteraction();
        }
    }
```

but it also does not work:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [org.apache.http.HttpRequest request] in method [public void com.swisscom.abusehq.anonymizer.pact.PactProviderTest.pactVerificationTestTemplate(au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit5.PactVerificationContext,org.apache.http.HttpRequest)].
```

Whole class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTestConfiguration.class})
@Provider("my-app")
@PactBroker
        (
                consumerVersionSelectors = @VersionSelector(tag = "developer-build"),
                authentication = @PactBrokerAuth(
                        username = "${pactbroker.auth.username}",
                        password = "${pactbroker.auth.password}"
                )
        )
@Slf4j
public class PactProviderTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MyController myController;

    @Mock
    MyService myService;

    @TestTemplate
    @ExtendWith(PactVerificationSpringProvider.class)
    public void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context, HttpRequest request) {
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        if (context != null) {
            context.verifyInteraction();
        }
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void before(PactVerificationContext context) {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        MockMvcTestTarget target = new MockMvcTestTarget();
        target.setControllers(myController);
        context.setTarget(target);
    }

    @State("account exists")
    public void notificationForAccount(Map data) {
        log.info("Now service in 'state 1' state: " + data);

        doNothing().when(myService).sendNotification(any(MyRequest.class));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
1.1) header: Expected a header 'Content-Type' but was missing
```

This message comes from the response validation on the provider side. It tells that pact expects the server returns `Content-Type` header and it dones't. Your application should be adjusted for this and the test, i.e. `@RestController` or something:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/url", produces = { "application/json" }
```